# Is it possible to get user input, possibly with a prompt, and display info messages with a spinner progress bar in terminal?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, rich, prompt-toolkit

Is there a way to get user input similar to a prompt, for example

```
from prompt_toolkit import PromptSession
from prompt_toolkit.patch_stdout import patch_stdout
import asyncio
import time


async def echo():
    while True:
        with patch_stdout():
            print(time.time())
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def read():
    session = PromptSession()

    while True:
        with patch_stdout():
            line = await session.prompt_async("> ")
            print(line)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(echo())
loop.create_task(read())
loop.run_forever()
```

and keep a spinner progress bar like those in https://github.com/pavdmyt/yaspin ?
Is there any library able to do this in python other than writing this from a scratch using curses?